# What is wrong with my MVC application?! (500 on Content and Scripts)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For anything under the Scripts or Content folders in my ASP.NET MVC application, I am getting the following error:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred

That's the response in its entirety (excepting the headers) - nothing else. I am hosting this on GoDaddy, and have not had problems with this application before. What did I do to screw this up?! Working on 4 hours of sleep isn't helping matters...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be appropriate here:

> "It takes considerable knowledge just to realize the extent of your own ignorance."
>
> ```
>                                                   -Thomas Sowell
> ```

So, when struggling to get a Flash-based, JavaScript-configured component to work in my web app, I added a *staticContent* node to my web.config, with a *mimeMap* node as a child:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        ...
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mpeg" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I commented-out the entire *staticContent* node, everything worked just fine. I didn't know that adding a *mimeMap* here would cause all of the default *mimeMap*s (specified within the server's ApplicationHost.config) to be overridden, because that seems to be exactly what is going on...Then again, I am merely guessing - either way, not very easy to figure out.

**Thank you to everyone that responded, I appreciate it!**

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config file, find the [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) section and change mode to Off.

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
</customErrors>
```

Changing that will give you a more descriptive error.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help - the response is directly from IIS on those files themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when upgrading to a newer version of IIS, though with a different  mime type.  As you also surmised, I believe the new version must already have the type registered (or the host did it at the machine level).  I solved it by putting "remove" before the "add" - all my content started showing up again.  I would think this would prevent having to modify the config between dev and prod.

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtensions=".mp4" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
</staticContent>
```

This has been edited to replace video/mpeg with video/mp4.  /mpeg still worked for me, but apparently mp4 is recommended.

Comment: this helped my case, where I hadd added mimeMap for .woff. Don't know why it was down voted.

Comment: Happened to me as well with an Azure Web Application. I'd added entries for SVG, WOFF and MP4. Needed to include the initial removes. No exceptions were being thrown; the only behavior is that JS and CSS files in the Scripts and Content folders were not getting to the client properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you turn off Simple error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try putting

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content");
```

in your route register?

Also make sure that if you are using the built-in authentication, you have this bit in your web.config, though I think it isn't your problem:

```
<location path="public">
    <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, do you have any control of IIS on that hosting?  Maybe they have a wildcard mapping interfering.  That's happened to us before with site minder.

Answer (score 0):

Download Phil Haack's [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx), then try navigating to one of the Scripts.  You might be catching them in your routes.